# Best way to store user's twitter followers' data

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures

I have to store all followers and friends of my members.

This can be 10k,20k rows for member

Example image : http://prntscr.com/1y4jxk

When my website reach 1k members, my database became huge ( in this way )

[

lets say avarage follower+friends = 3k;

(1k*3k = 3m rows)

]

how should i store that kind of data ?

Answer (score 0):

Your db is not a problem.

However problem is database setup.

For huge amount of data you have to use tables that are made on partition.

That is called database carnality.

Take a look at this manual on how to do that with mysql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Also on db cardinality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)

Partitons are just multiple different files for indexes and tables.

That mean that one table is located in many files as there are partitions.
This also apples  for index files. Instead of search one large file with 10k records you will search one file because index will now in what partition is that record is located.

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: I'm researching it now, i'll be back soon for questions :)

Comment: If i partition my table which hash(id), will it effect my select queries' speed ?